# Directly linking to nav tab not working in Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, deep-linking

I'm following instructions from Bootstrap 4 Beta docs
"Using data attributes
You can activate a tab or pill navigation without writing any JavaScript by simply specifying data-toggle="tab" or data-toggle="pill" on an element. Use these data attributes on .nav-tabs or .nav-pills."

according to this, I dont need any JS to make it work. if I change the url to include the hash example #profile , the tab won't show.

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">...</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czcz/k65she8u/)

full screen fiddle with direct link to the #profile tab
[fullscreenFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czcz/k65she8u/show/light/#profile)

Do I need to still use Js to read the url and get the hash? Using the current Beta version.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. Your tab sample is working. It appears not to work as all the content is the same "...". I changed it to 1, 2, 3, 4 depending on what content area was supposed to be showing, and the correct content appears.

Edit: Okay. I see what you're saying now. There wasn't any direct link in your initial fiddle link.

Comment: What URL? are you referring to the id of the tab?

Comment: I wanted to activate a tab based on the location hash. Example url#profile should automatically activate the tab profile. If navigates to url#home should automatically activate the home tab.

Comment: for example going to https://jsfiddle.net/czcz/k65she8u/show/light/#profile should automatically activate tab profile

Comment: Make sure you're not trying to develop in jsfiddle. Even the full page version uses an iframe.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with on my project. I'm just using Jsfiddle to show that I have tried.

Comment: Fair enough. Thought it worth mentioning just in case ...